# What is a proper way to handle a Variant type in VB6?

Tags: vb6, vb6-migration

I have a DLL (inaccessible at the moment) where a function returns a Variant()

This variant is theoretically should return an array of errors (if such occurred).

Dim iresult

iresult = object.functioncall()

I am trying to catch this result set whether it's empty or not. What I get right now is this:

?typename(iresult)
Variant()
?ubound(iresult)
 1 
?lbound(iresult)
 0 
?isempty(iresult)
False
?isnull(iresult)
False
?isarray(iresult)
True

Any attempt to get inside iresult(1) or iresult(0) or through a loop gives me a subscript out of range error. I can settle for array being empty but if it contains something i need to get it.

Any suggestions are welcome. Thank you.

Comment: just to be clear, the calling program is also VB6?

Comment: Yes, also VB6, an executable.

Comment: can you try Dim iresult() as Variant? Maybe it's getting confused.

Comment: I have tried that and got ?ubound(iresult) as a subscript out of range. I've looked at the code inside the dll and it seems that the array it tries to return is actually of typename empty. Maybe it has to do with that.

Comment: hmm. very odd. sorry I'm out of ideas.

Comment: what do you get with `?typename(iresult(0))`

Comment: I get subscript out of range

Answer (score 0):

After accessing the code I have realized that part of the issue was that array being returned was 2 dimensional. But I cheated anyway, because the array can come empty and Variant would not recognize it being empty or null.

By reiterating through returned Variant (which always comes back as an array or sorts) I catch the "out out of range" error and go one with my code. If it does reiterate then I would be fine as well.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Empty, Null, etc. are special values so if you are not using them then of course checks for these values will not work.  Instead you seem to be returning an undimensioned array, which is tougher to directly detect.  There are several possible "cures" but explaining them in a one-line response isn't easy.  Exception handling works, but there isn't anything mystical going on here.  You do not have a Variant function, you have a Variant Array function.  In the words of Master Yoda: "That is why you fail."

Comment: Makes sense. This is already more than I want to know about VB6 arrays.